# how to add unique values in elasticsearch arrays using java/scala

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, scala, elasticsearch

I have the following array in my ElasticSearch document:

```
"UserList":["1","2","3"]
```

And I want to update the the whole array and also add more unique values in it. For that I am doing something like this:

```
var userList = List("1","2","7","8")
for(n <- userList) {
    log.debug("what is userList " + userList)
    bulkRequest.add(client.prepareUpdate("testdb", ARTGROUP_COLLECTION_NAME, artGroup.uuid)
        .setScript("for(i in ctx._source.UserList){if(i!='"+n+"'){i += '"+n+"'}}",ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE))
}
```

But this does not update anything nor it adds the values to the array. How can I get this result:

```
"UserList":["1","2","3","7","8"]
```